Setting Bounds On Energy Scale from Wilson Coefficient
I am trying to extract the bounds for the energy scale of new physics $\Lambda$, knowing the bounds on the Wilson Coefficients. Usually, the Wilson coefficient in graphs comes in $C^2/\Lambda^2$, so essentially, if I am not mistaken, the bounds are set on the quantity $C^2/\Lambda^2$, for a given energy scale, for instance, 1TeV. The question concerns setting the bounds on the Energy scale $\Lambda$, from the bound on the Wilson Coefficient. My reasoning, goes as follows. Having the Wilson Coefficient bounds for 1 TeV, I should multiply the bound by 1 (TeV$^2$) to reinstate the dependence on $\lambda$ and then invert the relation So if $C^2/\Lambda^2=C_{bound}$ we have that by setting C=1 we get that $\lambda=\frac{1}{\sqrt{C_{bound}}}$. Is my reasoning correct. Is there something more in behind that I don't see?
Sorry for the naivity of the question, but I have been constantly to replicate certain results, which I fail to.

A Wilsonian effective Lagrangian (in four spacetime dimensions) has the form
$$
\mathcal{L} = \sum_i \frac{c_i}{\Lambda^{4-\Delta_i}} \mathcal{O}_i
$$
where $c_i$ are dimensionless coefficients, $\Lambda$ is the cutoff scale, and $\mathcal{O}_i$ are operators with mass dimension $\Delta$. Usually, we assume $c_i \sim O(1)$, so that $\Lambda$ represents the cutoff of the theory.
If you compute some S-matrix element or cross section using an effective action, typically it will involve some scaling with energy. For example, a cross section might scale as
$$
\sigma \sim E^2 \left(\frac{E}{\Lambda}\right)^k
$$
for some $k$. Now the actual expression will probably be some complicated mess involving lots of factors of $2\pi$ and various $c_i$ and so on, but the cutoff can be read off from the leading order scaling behavior at large energies.
This is basically what you wrote, but I just wanted to clarify a few things.
First, $c_i$ isn't usually literally equal to $1$. We need to measure these parameters (or derive them if we know the UV completion). Instead, what happens is that people assume the $c_i$ are approximately $1$, then derive an order of magnitude estimate from $\Lambda$ under that assumption. Setting the $c_i$ to $1$, dropping other numerical constants, and finding when a Taylor expansion is $E/\Lambda$ starts to break down, is a way to derive that approximation for the cutoff.
Second, it isn't true that Wilson coefficients always appear as $C^2/\Lambda^2$ in Feynman diagrams. Which Wilson coefficients appear in the diagram will depend on what operators/interactions appear as vertices in the diagram. For example, in a scalar field theory, there will be a Wilson operator like $\frac{c}{\Lambda^{5}}\phi^9$, and if the corresponding vertex appears in a diagram, that vertex will contribute a factor $\sim \frac{c}{\Lambda^5}$ according to the usual Feynman rules.
Finally, it's not safe to use an individual Feynman diagram to estimate the cutoff, since Feynman diagrams of the same order can cancel with each other. You should compute something physical like an $S$-matrix element to establish the cutoff. Having said that, people are often lazy and won't do this if there's no (or apparently no) symmetry that would lead to such a cancellation.

Thank you very much for your response. Tbh, I said $C^2/\Lambda^2$ because of the graphs. If I m not mistaken usually the exclusion graphs are presented as $C^2/\Lambda^2$. If not please correct me.

@Anthony1199 I don't know what you mean by "the graphs." If you mean Feynman graphs, then the order of $\Lambda$ that appears in a particular vertex of a graph will depend on which operator generates that vertex. If you mean there's some kind of experimental exclusion plot putting bounds on a specific operator, it may be that the operator in question is dimension $6$, so the coefficient of the operator in the Wilson action is $c/\Lambda^2$. Or maybe the operator is dimension $5$ (so the coefficient in the action is $c/\Lambda$), and the experimental process involves this vertex squared.

You are right. I mean exclusion graphs, where experiments set bounds on wilson coefficients. I m not referring to individual Feynman Diagrams

@Anthony1199 OK. Then I think the procedure you outline in your question is pretty much exactly right. I'm not 100% sure what context this is, but my guess is that you're looking at plots constraining a dimension 5 operator like one that you might see in the context of the seesaw mechanism for neutrino masses, and $C^2/\Lambda^2$ appears because the process being constrained involves two copies of this dimension 5 vertex.

Exactly. Thanks then
